# history.pushstate not working in IE8

Tags: javascript

I am using `window.History.pushstate`. It works fine in Chrome, but in IE8 it appends the path #.
Please help.

Below is my code snippet:

```
  var History = window.History; 
  History.pushState(null, null, "/abc");
```

Comment: [`window.History` isn’t supported in IE 8 (or, indeed, IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history).

Comment: **window.History** and **window.history** is not the same thing. window.history uses the HTML5 history API which ie8 can't use. window.History referes to History.js (see https://github.com/browserstate/history.js by Benjamin Lupton). History.js is almost the same as HTML5 History API only with fallback mechanisms for HTML4 only supported browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote window.History. Did you include [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) by Benjamin Lupton?
window.History and window.history is not the same thing as window.History referes to history.js and that makes the history backwards compatible with html4 browsers.

Take a look at these two:

- [jQuery & history.js example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553037/jquery-history-js-example)
- [jquery.history.js VS jquery-hashchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980735/jquery-history-js-vs-jquery-hashchange)

Answer (score 1):

you can refer below answer

[IE history push state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705241/ie-history-push-state)

IE9 and below don't support `pushState`. You have an exception when calling the following line:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, pathFullPage);

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'pushState' ?terms_and_conditions, line 62 character 21
```

You may probably be interested in looking at some workarounds discussed here: [Emulate/polyfill history.pushstate() in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622449/emulate-polyfill-history-pushstate-in-ie)

Comment: ”you can refer below answer given by Sergei Grebnov” — what answer is that?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: aha! I see.

Comment: I have taken the answer from another answer but I have given the name of the person who has given it..i don't think it is wrong!!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite cause Grebnov is a SO user

Comment: @Neel: if the question is a duplicate of another question, it should be marked as a duplicate. Could you link to where you got the answer from?

Comment: oh common I have read SO rules and its clearly mentioned that u can write another person answers but just mention the name of the author and I have done the same and ur behaving so rude to me it is sad believe me!

Comment: ok sorry @RokoC.Buljan  I will never refer like I did today but I don't think I am wrong I just wanted to help!! tc

Comment: @PaulD.Waite the above comment for u also

Comment: @Neel ok ok just making sure. Nothing personal, we have already collected too many duplicates here on SO (I'm also one that sometimes answers dupes but I try to always give an extra note and fresh value) but sometimes we see exact duplicates without giving credit to the OP. and that's bad :) happy coding!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes my mistake I will take care from next time..happy coding and no offence :)